# Не получается получить ответ на эту задачу, вроде все в порядке

Tags: javascript, строки

Дано число. Сложите его цифры. Если сумма получилась более 9-ти, опять сложите его цифры.
И так, пока сумма не станет однозначным числом (9 и менее).

```
var num = 1591;

function isSumLess() {
        var sum = 0;
        var arr = String(num).split('');
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr.shift();
        }

        if(sum > 9) {
            num = isSumLess();
        }else {
            return sum;
        }
    }
    isSumLess();
    document.write('Конечное число = ' + isSumLess());
```

Answer (score 2):

- Не используйте глобальные переменные, явно передавайте в функции параметры
- В функции внутри `if(sum > 9) {` нужно `sum` передавать
- Не используйте `arr.shift()` внутри цикла при итерации массива, иначе потеряются данные
- Явно приводите элементы массив к целому числу -- `parseInt`, т.к. складывая число со строкой получите строку:

  ```
  sum = 0
  // 0
  sum += '2'
  // "02"
  ```

Попробуйте:

```
function isSumLess(num) {
    var sum = 0;
    var arr = String(num).split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(arr[i]);
    }

    if (sum > 9) {
        return isSumLess(sum);
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}


var num = 1591;
let final_num = isSumLess(num);
document.write('Конечное число = ' + final_num);
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо, большое)

Comment: @МирасТекесбаев, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 0):

Все проще:

```js
var num = 1591;
function isSumLess(num) {
    if (num === 0) return 0;
    return (num - 1) % 9 + 1;
}

console.log('Конечное число = ', isSumLess(num));
```